# Management port and server port with X509 Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have an API that is authenticated by x509. However I need my actuator health check end point to be bypassed from authentication, so that I can do health check without client certificates.

I realized this can be done by using different ports for server and management where actuator endpoints will hit.

My application.yml config is as below:

```
server:
  port: 9000
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
    key-store-password: password
    key-password: password
    enabled: true
    trust-store: classpath:truststore.jks
    trust-store-password: password
    client-auth: need
    
management:
  server:
    port: 9010
    ssl:
      enabled: false
    security:
      enabled: false
```

My problem is that even with this configuration, management endpoint is not where I can access the health endpoint.
http://localhost:9010/health --> this doesn't work

I am still able to access it with the server port and certificates.
https://localhost:9000/health --> this works

My security configuration is as below :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .x509()
        .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                if (username.equals("user")) {
                    return new User(username, "", AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
                }
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!");
            }
        };
    }
```

I have the spring-boot-actuator dependency in my pom. I don't understand why my management port doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there anything in the application logs when you try to reach  `http://localhost:9010/health`?

Comment: Nothing, that's the strangest part

Comment: Do you get any response when you try to reach that endpoint? (e.g. 403 status code, or error message)

Comment: I get "Connection Refused"

Comment: Ok, that would suggest that it's not opening port 9010 at all. Not sure why; your application.yml looks ok.

Comment: Is this actually possible? I mean, having a server port which can handle x509 auth via https and management port which can be used for actuator endpoints via http?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong here. It was spring boot dependencies. I was using spring-boot-actuator, when I changed it to spring-boot-starter-actuator, the management port started listening to my configured port. I then disabled the SSL authentication on that port. Providing my config below so that it would be helpful for someone else:

```
management:
  server:
    port: 8000
    ssl:
      enabled: false

server:
  port: 9000
  ssl:
    key-store: classpath:keystore.jks
    key-store-password: password
    key-alias: alias
    key-password: password
    enabled: true
    trust-store: classpath:truststore.jks
    trust-store-password: password
    client-auth: need
```

Now I can access my actuator endpoints like health via http on port 8000 and my application rest APIs on port 9000 via https with valid client certificate.